# Rewriting Linear ODE for Control

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory

I'm working on a model for an engineering control project and I've run into the issue of having the control multiplied by the state variable in a differential equation. The simplified system looks something like:

$\dot{y}_1=y_2\\
\dot{y}_2=\left(a+g\left(t\right)\right)y_1+\left(b+cg\left(t\right)\right)y_2$

Here $y_1$ and $y_2$ are state variables, $g\left(t\right)$ is the control, and $a,b,c$ are constants. Ideally it'd be nice to take a Laplace transform and work with the standard $\dot{x}=Ax+Bu$ type system, but as it stands I have something that has an $x*u$ term. It seems like linearization in the differential equation sense is unnecessary since as it stands the system is linear, it just has variable coefficients.

One thought I had was to take a Taylor Series approximation, but I wasn't sure if that could be applied directly in this context.

Edit: If I do a Taylor series expansion of $H\left(t\right)=g\left(t\right)y_1\left(t\right)$ around some point $d$ I get:

$H\left(t\right)\approx H\left(d\right)+H'\left(d\right)\left(t-d\right)=g\left(d\right)y_1\left(d\right)+\left(g'\left(d\right)h\left(d\right)+g\left(d\right)h'\left(d\right)\right)\left(t-d\right)$

Which doesn't seem to help given that I've "lost" in some sense the control function all together.

Comment: The system *is* nonlinear. Just because (in this form) it looks like it has "only" variable coefficient doesn't make the system linear at all. As you wrote, you are multiplying a state variable with the input, which is a nonlinear operation. Also note that linearization *is* Taylor Series approximation (just truncated after the linear term).

Comment: Hmm, I'm probably just mixing up terms in different contexts here, but I thought as long as the differentiated terms appear linearly, than the ODE is classified linear? In any case, I understand that a Taylor series is linearization, I just didn't see it getting me anywhere in separating things out. I edited the original post to hopefully show what I mean. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It depends. You could for example take $g(t) = \sin(t)$, then you would get a linear time-varying system because your system would be of the form $\dot{x} = A(t)x$. If you take $g(t) = d$ (constant) you get a linear time invariant system $\dot{x} = A x$. But if you treat $g$ as input $u$ you get $\dot{x} = A(u) x$ which is nonlinear. Take for example $g(t) = y_2(t)$, you get a nonlinear system. It all depends on your choice of $g(t)$. Since you made no restrictions about $g$, we have to assume the most general case and that is your system is nonlinear.

Comment: Ok, I see what you are saying now. The goal is to treat $g$ as input, so $\dot{x}=A\left(u\right)x$ seems to be what I'm working with. Do you by chance know any reference information I could look to for analysis of this type of system? It seems like I'm not going to have any luck "decoupling" the state variables from the control.

Comment: The main problem of nonlinear control is that it is too broad. I do not know any book on your particular case other than the standard nonlinear systems textbook as Khalil or Slotine. On the other hand, your model does not look too complicated, and it depends on your goal. Do you want to stabilize it at a particular point? To track a particular trajectory?

Comment: We'd like to do stability analysis around a steady state profile if possible. The ODE system above actually comes from an original coupled systems of PDEs that we were able to separate out, and perform a separation of variables analysis on the result. This led to a second order variable coefficient ODE, and then to the above. One problem I see already is that the S.S. of the above either requires $y_{1s}=0$, $y_{2s}=0$. Or $y{2s}=0$ and $a=-g\left(t)\right)$ neither of which seem to be very useful for analysis.

Comment: The problem with this system is that you can lose controllability. For example if you end up at $y_1 = y_2 = 0$ you are stuck there forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the system

$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x}_1 &= x_2 \\
\dot{x}_2 &= (a + u) x_1 + (b c) u x_2
\end{align}
$$

At steady state, $x_2 = 0$ so if you are interested in steady state analysis it makes sense to control $x_1$. You could use the control

$$
u = \frac{k_1(x_{1,des} - x_1) - k_2 x_2 - a x_1}{x_1 + (b c) x_2}
$$

This makes your system behave like

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\dot{x}_1 \\
\dot{x}_2
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-k_1 & -k_2
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2
\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
k_1
\end{pmatrix} x_{1,des}
$$

as long as $x_1 + (b c) x_2 \neq 0$. This system is linear and has the transfer function:

$$
\frac{k_1}{s^2 + k_2 s + k_1}
$$

which is stable if $k_1 > 0$ and $k_2 > 0$.

---

We can test this. For example assume $a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, k_1 = 10, k_2 = 10$ and for the initial conditions $x_1(0) = 3$ and $x_2(0) = 0$. With the following trajectory we can see if tracking is possible:

$$
x_{1,des} = \begin{cases}
3 & t \in[0, 5) \\
4 & t \in[5, 15) \\
5 & t \in[15, 25) \\
4.5 & t \in[25, 35) \\
4 & t \geq 35
\end{cases}
$$

Simulate:

[image]

You can see that the controller works. It is possible to reach different steady state values of $x_1$. In the last plot you can see that the $x_1 + (bc) x_2$ remains far enough away from zero. This is something you have to make sure by selecting the $x_{1,des}$ trajectory and the parameters carefully.

It should probably work if you make only "small" steps with $x_{1,des}$ and wait until $x_2$ has decayed to zero before making the next step.

Comment: This is great, thanks a lot for the input!